# publisher subscriber pattern of zmq is not working as expected

Tags: node.js, design-patterns, publish-subscribe, message

I have simple sample program for pub/sub pattern in nodejs which is as shown below

publisher.js

```
var zmq = require('zmq');
var pub = zmq.socket('pub');

pub.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:6666');

console.log("Current 0MQ version is " + zmq.version);
var loop =0

pub.send(['t',loop++ + ' pub msg']);
pub.send(['t',loop++ + ' pub msg']);
```

subber.js

```
var zmq = require('zmq');
var sub = zmq.socket('sub');
sub.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:6666');

sub.subscribe('t');  //herein lies the question
console.log('Received msg:');
sub.on('message',function(topic, msg){
    console.log('Received msg:',msg.toString());
})
```

there are some unexpected behaviour which i am falling to understand from two days

1:for the first time when i run subber.js first and then 
publisher.js i will get the messages as expected

2:Again if i run in the same order i am not getting any messages (subber.js and publisher.js)

3: for first i run publisher.js and then subber.js  none of the messages i will get

really i am not understanding that sample program working or not please help me to understand publisher subscriber pattern of zmq with some sample code (**In the sample i have not used setinterval bcoz once the publisher send the message i have send to subscriber please provide the some sample to understand and accomplish this)

Thanks

Comment: please check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40689402/publisher-subscriber-pattern-of-zmq-is-not-working-as-expected

Answer (score 0):

When you start publisher first, publisher send msg (in nothing) so when subber starts, it can't get any msg.

First of all. You should use sync bind. Socket not created yet, but you already try to send something.

`pub.bindSync('tcp://127.0.0.1:6666');`

Nevertheless it didn't help me. I think bindSync work not sync (((. So I have to use timer to send something if application starts.

`setTimeout( () => {
     pub.send(['t',loop++ + ' pub msg']);
     pub.send(['t',loop++ + ' pub msg']);
}, 1000);`